# Apply different variables across different date range in Pandas

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe with dates and values from column A to H. Also, I have some fixed variables X1=5, X2=6, Y1=7,Y2=8, Z1=9

```
Date                     A      B        C   D      E   F   G    H
0   2018-01-02 00:00:00 7161    7205    -44 54920   73  7   5   47073
1   2018-01-03 00:00:00 7101    7147    -46 54710   73  6   5   46570
2   2018-01-04 00:00:00 7146    7189    -43 54730   70  7   5   46933
3   2018-01-05 00:00:00 7079    7121    -43 54720   70  6   5   46404
4   2018-01-08 00:00:00 7080    7125    -45 54280   70  6   5   46355
5   2018-01-09 00:00:00 7060    7102    -43 54440   70  6   5   46319
6   2018-01-10 00:00:00 7113    7153    -40 54510   70  7   5   46837
7   2018-01-11 00:00:00 7103    7141    -38 54690   70  7   5   46728
8   2018-01-12 00:00:00 7074    7110    -36 54310   65  6   5   46357
9   2018-01-15 00:00:00 7181    7210    -29 54320   65  6   5   46792
10  2018-01-16 00:00:00 7036    7078    -42 54420   65  6   5   45709
11  2018-01-17 00:00:00 6994    7034    -40 53690   65  6   5   45416
12  2018-01-18 00:00:00 7032    7076    -44 53590   65  6   5   45705
13  2018-01-19 00:00:00 6999    7041    -42 53560   65  6   5   45331
14  2018-01-22 00:00:00 7025    7068    -43 53500   65  6   5   45455
15  2018-01-23 00:00:00 6883    6923    -41 53490   65  6   5   44470
16  2018-01-24 00:00:00 7111    7150    -39 52630   65  6   5   45866
17  2018-01-25 00:00:00 7101    7138    -37 53470   65  6   5   45663
18  2018-01-26 00:00:00 7043    7085    -43 53380   65  6   5   45087
19  2018-01-29 00:00:00 7041    7085    -44 53370   65  6   5   44958
20  2018-01-30 00:00:00 7010    7050    -41 53040   65  6   5   44790
21  2018-01-31 00:00:00 7079    7118    -39 52880   65  6   5   45248
```

What I wanted to do is adding some column-wise simple calculations to this dataframe using values in column A to H as well as those fixed variables.

The tricky part is that I need to apply different variables to different date ranges.

For example, during 2018-01-01 to 2018-01-10, I wanted to calculate a new column I where the value equals to: (A+B+C)*X1*Y1+Z1; 
While during 2018-01-11 to 2018-01-25, the calculation needs to take (A+B+C)*X2*Y1+Z1. Similar to Y1 and Y2 applied to each of their date ranges.

I know this can calculate/create a new column I.

```
df[I]=(df[A]+df[B]+df[C])*X1*Y1+Z1
```

but not sure how to be able to have that flexibility to use different variables to different date ranges.

Comment: Please review [mcve] as well as [ask].  A sample output would be very helpful here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `np.select` to define a value based on a condition:

```
cond = [df.Date.between('2018-01-01','2018-01-10'), df.Date.between('2018-01-11','2018-01-25')]
values = [(df['A']+df['B']+df['C'])*X1*Y1+Z1, (df['A']+df['B']+df['C'])*X2*Y2+Z1]

# select values depending on the condition
df['I'] = np.select(cond, values)
```

Comment: it returns desired results.Thks